# Emoji support for NSAttributedString attributes (kerning/paragraph style)

Tags: ios, swift, unicode, nsattributedstring

I am using a kerning attribute on a `UILabel` to display its text with some custom letter spacing. Unfortunately, as I'm displaying user-generated strings, I sometimes see things like the following:

[image: /Users/mick/Desktop/Capture d’écran 2018-03-30 à 16.45.55.png]

ie sometimes some emoji characters are not being displayed.

If I comment out the kerning but apply some paragraph style instead, I get the same kind of errored rendering.

I couldn't find anything in the documentation explicitely rejecting support for special unicode characters. Am I doing something wrong or is it an iOS bug?

The code to reproduce the bug is available as a playground here: https://github.com/Bootstragram/Playgrounds/tree/master/LabelWithEmoji.playground

and copied here:

```
//: A UIKit based Playground for presenting user interface

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

extension NSAttributedString {
    static func kernedSpacedText(_ text: String,
                                    letterSpacing: CGFloat = 0.0,
                                    lineHeight: CGFloat? = nil) -> NSAttributedString {
        // TODO add the font attribute

        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.kern,
                                      value: letterSpacing,
                                      range: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.count))

        if let lineHeight = lineHeight {
            let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = lineHeight

            attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle,
                                          value: paragraphStyle,
                                          range: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.count))
        }

        return attributedString
    }
}

//for familyName in UIFont.familyNames {
//    for fontName in UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: familyName) {
//        print(fontName)
//    }
//}

class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        let myString = "1⚽⚾️‍♂️\n2  "

        let label = UILabel()
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 200, width: 200, height: 100)
        label.attributedText = NSAttributedString.kernedSpacedText(myString)
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.textColor = .black

        view.addSubview(label)
        self.view = view
    }
}
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

Thanks.

Comment: The code sample and your screenshot are a match? It transformed the thumb up emoji into theses two?

Comment: Your problem is probably this: `NSRange(location: 0, length: text.count)`. Swift's string counts using extended grapheme clusters. NSAttributedString uses the ObjC's encoding, which is UTF-16. Try changing that to `text.utf16.count`

Comment: @Larme they are.

Comment: @CodeDifferent: great idea. I hadn't thought of checking what ObjC's encoding was. It seems to do the trick. Why don't you submit your comment as an answer? :)

Comment: @CodeDifferent exactly, thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### TL, DR:

`String.count != NSString.length`. Any time you see `NSRange`, you must convert your `String` into UTF-16:

```
static func kernedSpacedText(_ text: String,
                                letterSpacing: CGFloat = 0.0,
                                lineHeight: CGFloat? = nil) -> NSAttributedString {
    // TODO add the font attribute

    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.kern,
                                  value: letterSpacing,
                                  range: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.utf16.count))

    if let lineHeight = lineHeight {
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = lineHeight

        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle,
                                      value: paragraphStyle,
                                      range: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.utf16.count))
    }

    return attributedString
}
```

---

#### The longer explanation

Yours is a common problem converting between Swift's `String` and ObjC's `NSString`. The length of a `String` is the number of *extended grapheme clusters*; in ObjC, it's the number of UTF-16 code points needed to encode that string.

Take the thumb-up character for example:

```
let str = ""
let nsStr = str as NSString

print(str.count)    // 1
print(nsStr.length) // 2
```

Things can get even weirder when it comes to the flag emojis:

```
let str = ""
let nsStr = str as NSString

print(str.count)    // 1
print(nsStr.length) // 4
```

Even though this article was written all the way back in 2003, it's still a good read today: 
[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).

Comment: this helped me with an issue I had with emojis breaking when applying kern

Comment: thank you so much for your answer!! fixed some nasty bugs with emojis breaking my text processing logic 